# Observavable combined with a setTimeout in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs5, angular-http

anybody knows if it is possible to set a Timeout on an http request using Observable, see my code bellow, what I would like is:
 as soon as my datas are changed in my web API (or backend server) I want  to refresh my datas in the view, then the user could know something new is happening...hope I am clear enough...if you don't understand please ask... Or another possibility is: every minute a function could make a new call to the server to check if there is some changes..

```
  export interface User {
 name: any[];
 data: any[];   
  }

 const userURL = 'http://my.apiserver.com';



@Injectable()
export class UserService {



 users: Observable<User[]>
    constructor (public http:Http) {
         this.users = http.get(usersURL)
                  .retry(3)  
                  .map(res => [res.json()]);

 }
```

Comment: Do you want to build some functionality like Long Polling?

Comment: So, do you want to test it periodically? Did you mean `setInterval`?

Comment: Usually server to client communication is handled with web sockets.

Comment: I don't understand if you want polling, or if you want to cancel your request after some amount of time.

Comment: First thanks @Akkusativobjekt , it's more like htttp+async pipe...maybe using flatmap? In other terms the server should tells to angular : "Hey ! Something as change please update the view !"

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe... I think it 's more a long pooling...because my app looks like a car dashbord... if the datas are increasing in the backend servor it as to increase same way in real time (or every minute at least in the view)

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology , the "normal" HTTP way is per request and response, and what you want is to push the client from the server.

Comment: thanks @Meir ...something like a Setintervall but just on the backend datas..

Comment: @Akkusativobjekt ..yes as a car dashboard.....when the engine is increasing the dashboard is increasing same way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`timer`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/timer.md) and [`switch`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/switch.md) operators:

```
this.users = Observable.timer(1000)
  .switch(() => http.get(usersURL).retry(3))
  .map(res => [res.json()])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Meir but it doesn't work as this state..maybe I have to adapt a little bit your code....look on top I update my post...

Comment: See what version of rxjs you use, v4 and v5 have different operators names. Try removing the retry(3) and see if it works. Also, add a `.do()` call after each state to see the flow

Comment: ...think it doesn't work because users is already an Observable " users: Observable<User[]>"

Comment: Code error is : "[ts] Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target."

Comment: I also use User as an interface ...I've update my post

Comment: I forget to mention that my code I posted on top of that subject is comming from a service, and I just use that service to log and get data from my backend server

Comment: Can you post it as a jsfiddle?

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle but I'm not sure if it help because I don't really know how to use jsfiddle with angular component : https://jsfiddle.net/1ezuya2m/

Comment: Thanks @Meir I find a way with that :   let tick$ = Observable.interval(5000);

        let response$ = 
          tick$
              .flatMap(() => http.get(usersURL))
              .map(res => [res.json()]);

    let stockPoller = response$.subscribe(res => console.log(res));

Comment: At the end I did an http polling ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can start with that

```
  private dataState = 'NotInitialized';
  private data = new BehaviorSubject<myObject>(null); // You can also use an empty object instead of null => to avoid null reference exceptions in your calling code


  getMyObject(): Observable<MyObject> {
    if (this.dataState === 'NotInitialized'){
      this.dataState = 'Initialized';

      setInterval(() => {
          this.http.get('myUrl')
           .map(res => res.json())
           .do(res => this.data.next(res))  // Maybe you can check if object has changed
           .subscribe(res => console.log(res)); // Subscribe is important! => otherwise, there is no consumption of this observable
      }, 1000); 

    }

 return this.data;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @deblaton-jean-philippe I 'll try this out